# Best way to smooth/filter a stream of data

Tags: filter, stream, smoothing

I have a stream of integer data (data coming in over time) that looks something like this.

[46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, `46`, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, `46`, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, `46`, `47`, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 100, 100, 100, `70`, 100, 100]

Basically, it's a stream of integers where the last integer is displayed on a screen. Sometimes, noise (a "bad" integer) is displayed for a short time causing the screen to flicker the integer. I'd like to avoid this flickering by not displaying noise.

I want to filter/remove numbers that only occur ~1-2 times in a row since they're generally noise. If a new integer comes in, it could either be noise or not depending on whether the next 1-2 integers are the same or not.

A little latency is ok. I'd like to avoid averaging the data since if a number jumps from 40 to 100, I'd like it to not scoop into 100 (ie. 40, 60, 80, 100) and instead be 100 as soon as deemed non-noise.

What's the best technique for smoothing/filtering this type of data?

Comment: thanks, I added a little more information. While the data is a stream, it's ok for some latency.

Comment: are you referring to `java.util.stream`?

Comment: no, just a general `stream`. Meaning, the data is coming in over time.

Comment: Mind showing us an input-output example?

Comment: I would compare to the last value and include it if it is the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey but that would never allow for a new number to be included, right? Since a new number would never match the last value if its a different number.

Comment: if the use the last input, not the last accepted value, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am not a signal processing expert, but I have some basic experience (let's call it that). Also, I have seen your other (possibly related) questions and you were talking about tuners and musical notes. Assuming this is related to that problem (?).

**Short answer:**

---

You can use local short-buffer filtering with median or mode. In the simplest form, by what you've described, you can 'safely' eliminate values that fall outside some pre-defined noise threshold and occur only once in current buffer.

**Long answer:**

---

In statistics, there is something called [MODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) besides standard [AVERAGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) and [MEDIAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median):

In the case of your entire 39-values array you gave as an example in your question:

main_array_values_by_occurrence = [46 => 13 times, 47 => 20 times, 70 => 1 time, 100 => 5 times]

```
average = 54.05 => 54 rounded
median  = 47
mode    = 47
```

Mode and Median functions can help you a lot to determine which value should be the representative value. In essence, mode is similar as ordering values by occurrence and value ascending, but it is not always clear what is the value of it in multi-modal distributions.

You can see that using average is not that great in case where you have occasional, particularly large, spikes.

Median sounds attractive as a major candidate for comparison algorithm, but what should you use? Median or Mode? It really depends on the type of data you are working with and their distribution. For example, if, say, we are detecting pitch of an instrument (musical notes) and we have a decent accuracy of our detector, mode method sounds like a good choice, because median might be misleading. If our tuner detected 60% of the time note A4 and 40% of the time other notes, on "average" it detected A4 because that tone was dominant in our data stream. More on Mode use cases also on above link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)#Use).

---

First, capture stream in a group of, say, 5 consecutive values (arbitrary buffer size or "scan" interval: smaller buffer means less effectiveness; larger buffer means less resolution and longer delays) and store them in array:

```
array_1 = [46 (first in) 46 46 47 47 (last in)]
```

You can also group them (count by occurrence) if you expect data to be mostly constant. This will give you some starting analysis point for the captured group.

```
array_1_occur = [46 => 3 47 => 2]
```

Then, you can use simple comparative algorithm to determine relative difference between them in consecutive way; you can store those values and +/- difference in a separate array.

```
array_1_diff = [0 0 0 +1 +1]
```

The simplest filtering can be easy at this stage, all values that are over the threshold and have low occurrence (<2 for example) can be instantly eliminated. If you wish to make it more robust, you have to consider next buffer batch as well and eliminate them only if they are truly single instances in the local group (including neighbors).

You need to define a threshold for your "noise", call it "noise threshold" or tolerance for simplicity. Say, if the value which occurs only once jumps over +10 from the previous buffer's median or mode it is "marked" as noise and further analysed.

```
array_2 = [46 46 90 47 47]

array_2_min = 46
array_2_max = 90
array_2_avg = (46+46+90+47+47) : 5 = 55.2
array_2_local_avg_ref = round(55.2) = 55 ( <-- useless in this case because median() value 47 is VERY DIFFERENT from average value! => thus we DISCARD it from analysis and mark value of 90 as a major SUSPECT )
```

In the case of array_1 example:

```
array_1_avg = 46
array_1_med = 47 (you order values from lowest to largest and take the middle one as median)
array_1_mod = 46 (not sure 100% about bi-modal or multi-modal cases at least in Excel a value of 46 is returned possibly as the lowest integer with highest occurrence in the ordered list. You can customize that in the event of multi-mode or no mode distribution algorithm fallback to median)
```

Then, you have to decide if you are going to drop it or keep it.

How? Well, if in array of 5 values all your values are ~ same (with respect to tolerance) except that single data point, it is obviously a noisy candidate. It can be determined from median or mode value comparison. The worse case scenario will be if the group contains all 5 different values. In that case, the value closest to the value of the previous captured group will be set as reference point. But, what if next array of 5 contains all values in the ~ same range as the noisy candidate? So for this reason we need to keep it until next 5 values come in for comparison and analysis. If the candidate is still far off the "norm" we can confirm that it is noise or singular random-like event (insignificant). If, on the other hand, we find at least one value that is near it (remember the threshold or step) than we keep it.

You will have a delay in output stream of at least N x buffer_length data points (samples): for basic N=2 (past+present) or N=3 (past+present+future) or even more.

---

Some simple observations: if the step is just +/- 1, then any value that jumps from the "norm" will be considered as noise. Problem here is what if the values start fluctuating a lot, say, every consecutive sample is +/- 1 respectively (oscillation event)? In that case you will have a problem to determine what is a "norm", because you work with integers only. This can be kind of solved by keeping an average value of, say, last 15-50-100 data samples and retrieving the last stable value in that case (no change).

"Ideally" you should keep 3* buffers: previous current and future one for analysis. Previous one is required for reference for the current and "future" one is required to improve transients (jumps to new values in the semi-steady stream).

Actually, you don't need 3 (or N) buffers. One buffer is just fine, but you can internally splice it to sections (say, buffer of 15 samples internally divided in 3 sections), which will greatly simplify processing (this part might not be obvious, so I've mentioned it).

In any case, you need to analyse your samples, try to figure their distribution, then build the algorithm and experiment with your actual data stream and tweak it. And inevitably you will lose some frequency or spatial resolution (depends on the type of signal) determined by the length of the local groups (buffers).

Of course, using some conditions like checking the distance between current sample and median/mode value and removing noisy samples is kind of a cheating, because it's not a "real" NR algorithm like some convolution or whatever. It's a shortcut given this specific case.

You will never be able to eliminate the fluctuation completely unless you create a very large buffer and then use learning or slow-adapting local group algorithm to minimize the fluctuation (noise) but preserve transients as much as possible which you explicitly mentioned. With "live" signals/streams where the delay is critical you have to keep buffering minimal which negates the possibility of "ideal" filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. It'll take me a little time to digest, but this is definitely helpful.